# Getting a nullPointerException in getting getLastCellNum() method in a blank Row, using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

My scenario is, I have to quit the conversion of `Excel` to `txt`, when a blank row appears.
I have written the following code for it

```
for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++)
{                       
   Row row=sheet1.getRow(rowNum);
   int lastColumn = row.getLastCellNum();
   for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) 
   {                    
       Cell cell = row.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);       
       if(cell == null)
       {
           break;
       }
       switch(cell.getCellType()) 
       {
           //Remaining code for non-blank cells
       }
   }
}
```

The code works fine, but as soon as a blank row appears, a `nullPointerException` is thrown 
in the `getLastCellNum()` method in line 4. Am I doing something wrong? Also I have set the missing cell policy for my workbook as

```
workbook1.setMissingCellPolicy(Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
```

Comment: Your sheet1.getRow(rowNum) is returning null because your row doesn't exist (is a blank row), you have to create it first.

Comment: You should use RowIterator and CellIterator to retrieve rows and cells.

Comment: But, in my scenario, I have to quit the conversion as soon as I face a blank row, and write the content of my BufferedWriter to the text file.
@Ammar I tried that initially, but both these iterators ignore blank rows. So if I have some data after some blank rows, that will be incuded in my output. I dont want that

Comment: Row row=sheet1.getRow(rowNum);
if (row != null) {
   // Your code
}

Comment: @fr0st, you can always break your loop if you encounter an empty or null row.

Comment: In poi we can't check for a blank row simply by using row!=null, we have to iterate over the cells an check for every cell in the row, atleast that's what I read on the internet.
EDIT: I read it over here
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this case may happen, if you want to find the lastCellNum of any null row, and the last row number of that sheet is more than the current row number.

For example, if total number of row is 10 in the sheet, but the 5th row is null. Null means not blank, but UN-initialized row. In that case `Row row=sheet1.getRow(rowNum);` will not show any error but `row.getLastCellNum();` will show `nullPointerException`

To overcome this issue you need to check before getting last row number that the row should not be null.

Please check the following piece of code

```
   int lastColumn=0;
    for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++){
        Row row=sheet1.getRow(rowNum);
        if(row!=null)
            lastColumn = row.getLastCellNum();
        else
            continue;
        for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++){
            Cell cell = row.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            if(cell == null){
                break;
            }
            switch(cell.getCellType()){
               //Remaining code for non-blank cells
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and provide my feedback.